# How to implement a Rewrite in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Can I do rewrites with Nginx,  I know it can do redirects using the rewrite or return commands but can it do rewrites like Apache htaccess does where if you don't specify a redirect flag it will not redirect the browser but show the other content.

I want to display specific URLs with just the folder location and not the filename.  In Apache I would just do the following with out R flag

RewriteRule ^/path/$ /path/filename.html [QSA,NE,L]

Can I do this with nginx

Comment: Use the [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) or [`rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite). Either will perform an internal redirection.

Answer (score 0):

No decent documentation anywhere but playing around with it,  looks like the rewrite directive works similar to apache but I need to use the break flag

rewrite ^/path/$ /path/filename.html break;